# Craft 3 Custom Set Password Styles

Tags: craft3, users, password, frontend-form

I've been building frontend pages for non-admin users with layouts matching the rest of the enduser site. For the "Set Password" page, I was able to build the form and set it up via the setPasswordPath config, no problem.

However, in addition to all my necessary frontend styles, this page also brings in a number of admin-side styles and scripts that greatly interfere with the layouts. Since any users seeing this custom page won't have admin access, these included files are certainly unneeded.

Outside of hacking the core, is there a more friendly way to exclude admin-level content on this non-admin page?

Answer (score 1):

This was a complication due to using the same browser for different user testings. Once all semblance of my admin user session/cookies were absent, the admin styles and scripts no longer appeared on this page.